# Regular expression in PHP for anchor tag

Tags: php, regex, anchor

I am using this regular expression

```
(preg_replace( "/\bany word\b/", `"<a href="abc@domain.com">any word</a>"` , 
$content))
```

in my code, this is for replacing the given keyword with the given anchor tag, but if there is already a link in the `$content` then it would not changed the keyword or link with the new link! For this I used

```
(preg_match( "/\A<a\s.+>.*\banyword\b.*<\s*\/a\s*>\z/", $content))
```

but if inside the `$content` there are many keywords with the same name and some are links and some others are not link then how I replace that keywords with the link.

Comment: This is a problem solved many times here on this site alone. Search.

Comment: Are you processing the content many times? sometimes the links are set in a script and/or sometimes the replacement passes 2 times? the content is coming from different sources but everything passes through the same filter? it begs the question, and I pray for an answer.

Comment: Yes i process the content many times, actually if there is more keywords in the content some are inside the anchor tag and some are simple keywords then i want that only the keywords are replaced not the keywords inside the anchor tag, like this "how you '<a href="abc">'care'</a>' your family also care", now i want that only the second "care" is replaced not the first anchor's "care"

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I searched but i can't find the answer as my requirement...

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I can help you any better, I'm not a RE guru for such a task, so this will be up to some other users to help out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need negative look ahead and look behind to solve this. Take a look at the chapter [Assertions](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) in the PHP manual.

You are using already negative look ahead and look behind by the use of the word boundary operator `\b`. The word boundary is a non word character followed by a word character or a word character followed by a non word character. All characters are not captured.

```
(?:\w)(?=\W)|(?:\W)(?=\w)
```

But you do not need word boundaries. You need to match a string, that is not part of a anchor. Being not part of an anchor means, there must not be a closing anchor tag or a second half of a string, followed by the anchor text and the closing anchor tag. It is expressed by this regular expression:

```
<?
$content = 'Send it to abc. <a href="abc@old.com">abc</a> needs it.';

$content = preg_replace ('/(abc)(?!([^\"]*\">[^<]*)?<\/a>)/',
             '<a href="abc@domain.com">$1</a>',
             $content);
echo $content, "\n";
?>
```

This script will generate the following output:

```
$ php look-around.php 
Send it to <a href="abc@domain.com">abc</a>. <a href="abc@old.com">abc</a> needs it.
```

It will replace only the first `abc`.  For your anchor you have to do it the other way round.

Comment: it works fine in above condition but not in this condition               $content = 'Send it to abc. <a href="abc@old.com">my abc</a> needs it.';

Comment: @Adeel "abc" is the unique identifier. A "my abc" can not be in the anchor text, if the anchor has been crafted from an "abc". If you need to do more than one replacement, you have to execute a `preg_replace` for each of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer you are almost nearer of my scenario but there is little bit changing, your first REGEX is almost right but i think that there is need of using of word boundry, when abc is present outside the anchor tag like this 'my name is abc' then it must be replace with a given link but in case if it is inside the anchor tag like this "my name '<a href="asa@domain.com"> is abc </a>'" then this one would not be changed...

Comment: First: my code does not show the anchor replacement, only the non-anchor replacement, because the non-anchor replacement is the complicated and the anchor replacement is the easy one. If you need a sub string match in the anchor, write a regular expression for that: `[^>]*(abc)[^<]*`. And second: you did not answer the question: if you craft the anchor by matching `(abc)` and producing a `>$1<`, where the "is " comes from?